# How to check input string must follow below sequence?

Tags: javascript, java, regex, string, validation

I have a String and I just want to validate the following string

`one=1&two=2` - This string would be considered valid

`23=2&sa=32fd`- This string would also be considered valid

`12one=&13&=3` - This string would be considered invalid

What is the best way to go about validating strings such as these?

Comment: Rather than show examples of valid and invalid strings, you must be able to explain (via patterns) what is and isn't valid. Right now, it is unclear what your logic is.

Comment: JavaScript or Java?

Comment: javascript and java are different languages, which one are you using?

Comment: Both are ok but java is much comfortable for me

Comment: Looks like you want to parse [Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) parameters. If thats the case i would use one of the dozens already existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using regex, you could use this:

```
^(?:\w*?=\w*?&?)+$
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1UxCSa/6)

```js
const regex = /^(?:\w*?=\w*?&?)+$/gm;
const str = `
one=1&two=2
23=2&sa=32fd
12one=&13&=3`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

However i would recommend looking into some [Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) parsing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The following will validate the full string as well as capture the individual matches

```
^([\w|\d]+\=[\w|\d]+\&?)+$
```

If you just want to validate the string only then Olian04's answer works